# PyTorch: one dimension in input data

Tags: pytorch

I don't understand why this code works:

```
# Hyperparameters for our network
input_size = 784
hidden_sizes = [128, 64]
output_size = 10

# Build a feed-forward network
model = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_sizes[0]),
                      nn.ReLU(),
                      nn.Linear(hidden_sizes[0], hidden_sizes[1]),
                      nn.ReLU(),
                      nn.Linear(hidden_sizes[1], output_size),
                      nn.Softmax(dim=1))
print(model)

# Forward pass through the network and display output
images, labels = next(iter(trainloader))
images.resize_(images.shape[0], 1, 784)
ps = model.forward(images[0,:])
```

The size of an image is *(images.shape[0], 1, 784)* but our networks has *input_size = 784*. How does the network handle 1 dimension in an input image? I tried to *change images.resize_(images.shape[0], 1, 784)* to *images = images.view(images.shape[0], -1)* but I got an error:

```
IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)
```

For reference, data loader is created the next way:

```
# Define a transform to normalize the data
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                              transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,)),
                              ])
# Download and load the training data
trainset = datasets.MNIST('~/.pytorch/MNIST_data/', download=True, train=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyTorch networks take inputs as [batch_size, input_dimensions]

In your case, images[0,:] is of the shape [1,784] where “1” is tue batch size and that is why your code works.